# Buffer Overflow shell question

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

If a custom library is affected by a buffer overflow and it is linked against an executable running as root. If an attacker gains a remote reverse shell, it will run under the user of the linked executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library that links against an executable will share all attributes of the process, including UID. For example, a vulnerable OpenSSL library linking against an executable whose process is running as `www-data` will, if exploited, give access to that user. If the same exact library is linked against an executable whose process is running as `root`, then exploitation will give access to *that* user.